# Map from algebraic curve to $\mathbb{P}^1$ an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let  $C$ be a connected algebraic curve proper over a field $k$. Let $P$ and $Q$ be distinct closed points of $C$. Let $ f$ be a meromorphic function on $C$ such that $div(f)=P-Q $. By valuative criteria for properness $ f$ induce a morphism of schemes $f:C \to \mathbb{P}^1_k$. Is this morphism an isomorphism? 
Do I need to assume $k$ is algebraically closed?

Comment: You have to assume that $P$ (and therefore $Q$) is $k$-rational, not just a closed point. If $k$ is algebraically closed, this is automatic.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks for the comment. what about the map $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{R}$ induced by the inclusion $\mathbb{R}[x, y] \to \mathbb{C}[x, y]$ and $f=x/y$? I believe here $P$ $Q$ are rational points, and the map isn’t an isomorphism, right?

Comment: All bets are off if $C$ is not geometrically irreducible.